# How to echo a environment variable contains a '&' in DOS batch?

Tags: batch-file, dos, echo

When I type:

```
set hi=Hello^&World!
echo %hi%
```

it print Hello and tell me World is not a command

I want it prints Hello&World!

How to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works for me:

```
set "hi=Hello^&World!"
echo %hi%
```

Outputs

```
Hello&World!
```

Answer (score 5):

The only secure way to echo the content of a variable is to use the delayed expansion here.
If percent expansion is used, it depends on the content if it fails.

```
set "var1=Hello ^& World"
set "var2=Hello & World"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !var1!
echo !var2!
echo %var1%
echo %var2% -- fails
```

The delayed expansion is more usefull as it doesn't interpret any special characters.
More info at [SO: How the parser works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

Answer (score 3):

just

```
echo Hello ^& World!
```

works

**EDIT**
so the problem is not with `ECHO` command, but with the assignment of the variable, as @Bali correctly pointed out.